# Taylor's Truncation Term for the Function $(1-x)^{-1}$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

For $f(x)=(1-x)^{-1}$ and $x_{0}=0$, I am trying to find a value of $n$ necessary for Taylor's $n$-th term $P_{n}(x)$ to approximate $f(x)$ to within $10^{-6}$ on $[0,0.5]$. I have formed the Taylor's remainder term $R_{n}(x)$ as follows:

$R_{n}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\eta)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!(1-\eta)^{-n-2}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=(1-\eta)^{-n-2}x^{n+1}$

Such that $\eta$ is between $x$ and $x_{0}$. But my problem is that the term $(1-\eta)^{-n-2}$ is increasing on $[0,0.5]$ and I am unable to find an upper bound for the remainder term. Could you please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Your formula has a small error in it. Anyway, as you say the worst possible case is when $\eta=x$. However there is an easier way to do this using the geometric series. Going via the Lagrange remainder you can only guarantee convergence on $[0,1/2)$.

Comment: I do not know Lagrange remainder. But my instructor has asked me to solve this with Taylor's remainder term.

Comment: @mali1234 The Lagrange remainder term is what you called "Taylor's remainder term".

Comment: As I said, you actually cannot prove this with the Lagrange remainder at $x=1/2$ because you can't be sure that $\eta$ doesn't go to $1/2$ as $n \to \infty$. So as stated this exercise is not possible.

Comment: I just found this exercise in Richard Burden's Numerical Analysis and he has provided the answer $n=19$ for this problem. Are you sure that this exercise is impossible? I checked the values and $n=19$ does produce error less than $10^{-6}$.

Comment: The actual error can be calculated exactly in this case. It is $\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, so that $n>-\log_2(\epsilon)$ is sufficient to get error less than $\epsilon$ on all of $[0,1/2]$. But that isn't using the Lagrange remainder.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you came up with this formula?

Comment: What does this have to do with Taylor's polynomial?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$ is the Taylor polynomial of $n$th degree of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ at $x_0=0$. But one can show that $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ (you have probably seen this already actually, if not it is straightforward to check).  So $|R_n(x)|= \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{1-x}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ (the interval of convergence of the series).